# How do I get the first 100 prime powers bigger than 255?

Tags: python, csv, primes

How do I get the first `100` prime powers `p^m\geq 255`?, where `p` is a prime and `m` is a positive integer.  Desired prime powers `p^m\in\{256, 289, 343, 361, 512, 529, 625, 729, 841, 961, 1024, 1331, 1369, 1681, 1849, 2048, 2187, 2197, 2209, 2401, 2809, 3125, 3481, ...\}`

**MWE:**
    import csv

```
fPm=open('primepm.csv', 'w')
writerPm = csv.writer(fPm)
writerPm.writerow(['P^m','Pm'])

p=2
countpm=0
while p<2^8:
    for m in range(8):
        if (p^m>=256 and p^m<1000):
            writerPm.writerow([str(factor(p^m)),str(p^m)])
            countpm=countpm+1
    p=next_prime(p)
    if countpm==100:
        break
```

But this program does not give the proper result.

Comment: `^` is the binary XOR operator. You probably want `**` for exponentiation.

Comment: You want p^m to be prime.  You appear to have forgotten m = 1.  353^1 is a prime power > 255

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the first 100 prime powers bigger than 255?

You can use the class `Sieve` from `sympy` ([see docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html)):

```
from sympy import sieve

for n in range(100):
    print(sieve[7+n]**2)
```

Output:

```
289
361
529
841
961
1369
1681
1849
2209
2809
3481
3721
4489
5041
5329
6241
6889
7921
9409
10201
10609
11449
11881
12769
16129
17161
18769
19321
22201
22801
24649
26569
27889
29929
32041
32761
36481
37249
38809
39601
44521
49729
51529
52441
54289
57121
58081
63001
66049
69169
72361
73441
76729
78961
80089
85849
94249
96721
97969
100489
109561
113569
120409
121801
124609
128881
134689
139129
143641
146689
151321
157609
160801
167281
175561
177241
185761
187489
192721
196249
201601
208849
212521
214369
218089
229441
237169
241081
249001
253009
259081
271441
273529
292681
299209
310249
316969
323761
326041
332929
```

The `7+` is there because the seventh prime power is the first prime power greater than 255.

The `100` in `range(100)` can be changed into a variable if you can to be able to dynamically choose how many prime powers greater than 255 you want to print.